# Vertical grid alignment between div header and content when content has a scroll bar

Tags: html, css

Please see this codepen: https://codepen.io/thummper/pen/MWXZdRJ or the snippet below

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.checkboxicon-unchecked:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome" !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  content: "" !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: #336699 !important;
}

.fileGrid,
.fileExplorerItem {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px repeat(2, 70px) 1fr 105px;
}

.fileGrid .itemActions a::before {
  color: #ff7a33 !important;
}

.fileGrid div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.fileGrid .breadcrumb {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.fileGrid .progressWrapper {
  grid-column: 2/5;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.fileGrid .progressWrapper .progress {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.fileGrid .itemActions {
  grid-column: 5/6;
}

.fileName::before,
.navigation::before,
.singleDownloadButton,
.singleDeleteButton,
.eye,
.eyeSlash {
  color: black;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .name {
  overflow: clip;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .file .name {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .file .ext {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .file .size {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .file .itemActions {
  grid-column: 5/6;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .folder .name {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .folder .itemActions {
  grid-column: 5/6;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .fileExplorerItem {
  padding: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .itemActions {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .itemActions a {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .progress {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #919ec7;
  box-shadow: rgba(17, 17, 26, 0.1) 0px 0px 16px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto 12px;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .progress .progressText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .progress .progress-bar {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #283869;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .headerRow {
  background-color: #566db5;
  padding: 10px 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .headerRow .fileBreadcrumb {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .folderName::before {
  content: "";
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .singleDeleteButton::before {
  content: "";
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .singleDownloadButton::before {
  content: "";
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .eye::before {
  content: "";
}

.fileExplorerWrapper .eyeSlash::before {
  content: "";
}

.directorylist {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  min-height: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.name>a:before {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.name>a.jpg:before,
.name>a.jpeg:before,
.name>a.png:before,
.name>a.ico:before,
.name>a.bmp:before,
.name>a.tiff:before,
.name>a.tif:before,
.name>a.gif:before,
.name>a.webp:before {
  content: "";
}

.noFilesSplash {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.noFilesSplash img {
  filter: opacity(0.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div id="content_file_explorer" class="fileExplorerWrapper">
  <div class="fileExplorer">
    <div class="headerRow fileGrid">
      <div class="fileBreadcrumb">
        \empdocs\6159
      </div>

      <div class="progressWrapper">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuenow="60883" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="125"></div>
          <div class="progressText">
            <span> 0.06 MB / 125 MB</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="itemActions">
        <a class="checkboxicon-unchecked" id="fileBulkCheck"></a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="fileBrowser">



      <div class="noFilesSplash hidden" style="pointer-events: none">
        <img src="/Content/Images/LivePayBW.png">
      </div>


      <ul class="directorylist" id="explorerList">


        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="fileExplorerItem file">
          <div class="name">
            <a class="fileName png" target="_blank">AddExpense.png</a>
          </div>
          <div class="ext"></div>
          <div class="size"></div>

          <div class="itemActions">
            <a class="eye singleHideButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDeleteButton"></a>

            <a class="singleDownloadButton donwloadSingleFile"></a>

            <a class="downloadCheckbox checkboxicon-unchecked"></a>
          </div>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the #fileBulkCheck checkbox to vertically align with checkboxes in the .directorylist ul.

The header row and the li's in the directory list use the same grid layout, but become misaligned when the ul expands past 500px - the set max width.

When the scrollbar appears it pushes everything towards the left - but as far as I can tell there is no well supported way to change the behaviour of this scroll?

I can vertically align them by placing a useless scrollbar on my header, but I'm not sure if I can make it invisible // It would not respect the child content unless the scrollbar is always visible.

Any suggestions to achieve this please?

Comment: Please turn the code into a stack overflow snippet that uses the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce your issue

Comment: Add   scrollbar-gutter: stable; to .directorylist which will position the elements as if there was a scroll bar, even if one isn't needed then position your #fileBulkCheck checkbox  above it.

Comment: Adding scrollbar-gutter gets me the desired behaviour - i was not aware of this CSS selector. Is there anything that would include Safari support?

Comment: I think safari uses overlay scrollbars so probably isn't relevant. I'll grab the wife's macbook and have a look

Comment: In that case, if Safari is not relevant, feel free to post your solution below and I can select it as the answer! Thanks (: